# getIntent method of com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following an example in a book titled "The definitive guide to Firebase" by L Moroney. It has the following code:

```
      public static Intent createIntent(Context context, IdpResponse           
       idpResponse)
      {
         Intent in = IdpResponse.getIntent(idpResponse);
         in.setClass(context, SignedInActivity.class);
         return in;
      }
```

I am getting an error when calling getIntent - cannot resolve method. Seems to me the method was there before (hence the code in the book)but has been made obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

There is `toIntent()` now there, but things are pretty dynamic there and the semantics could be all different now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may work

```
return new Intent().setClass(context, SignedInActivity.class)
  .putExtra(ExtraConstants.IDP_RESPONSE, response);
```